# Does a man praying with his head covered dishonor God?

Tags: contradiction

In the New Testament it's written that a man praying or prophesying dishonors his head; Meshiach Yeshua called Jesus the Christor God. But in the Old Testament the high priest wore turban.

> 1 Cor 11:4, 7 - Every man who prays or prophesies with his head covered
> dishonors his head. ... A man ought not to cover his head, since he is the image and glory of God; but the woman is the glory of man

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  Valid questions here must have a specific Bible reference.

Comment: The High Priest typfied the coming Messiah (Christ) and therefore it was in order for that person to wear a head covering, indicating headship. Nowadays, with Christ come (and ascended) any man praying is not to cover his head as this would indicated headship of himself. Thus, it would dishonour the true Head : Jesus Christ who is Lord.